# Extracting pixels from a raster based on specific value of another raster using R

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, r-raster

I imported two rasters (raster `A` and `B)`in R using the `raster` function.
I would like to extract the pixels of `A` where `B` equals 1 into a data frame.
I am trying the following, however, all the pixels I obtain have the same values, although they are various in the original dataset.

The two rasters have the same dimensions (ncols, nrows, ncell, resolution, extent, projection).

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# import inputs
A <- raster('/pat/to/rasterA.tif')
B <- raster('/pat/to/rasterB.tif')

# extract raster values from A over raster B where B == 1
mydata <- data.frame(A[B[B == 1]])
```

**EDIT 1**

Might be that when I do `A[B[B == 1]]`, the class of object A and B from `RasterLayer` becomes `numeric`, and this creates problems? I discovered this by doing `class(A[B[B == 1]])`, which gives `numeric`.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, this is weird. I tried to do `mydata <- data.frame(A[B])` and now the output has the original `A` only at `B == 1` locations. Trying this before it extracted all the pixels from `A` (as I would expect). I can coinfirm it is right by counting the number of ones in `B` and the number of elements in `mydata`, which is the same. It's like if the indexing has skipped all the zeros in `B`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: usually in r TRUE is translated to 1 and FALSE to 0. So, maybe the raster is interpreting the vector with 0 and 1 as FALSE and TRUE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example data:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1)
set.seed(1010)
A <- setValues(r, sample(0:5, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
B <- setValues(r, sample(0:2, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
```

Now you can do:

```
s <- stack(A,B)
v <- as.data.frame(s)
v[v[,2] == 1, 1]
```

Alternatively:

```
A[B==1]
```

Or:

```
D <- overlay(A, B, fun=function(x,y){ x[y!=0] <- NA; x})
na.omit(values(D))
```

Or:

```
xy <- rasterToPoints(B, function(x) x == 1)
extract(A, xy[,1:2])
```

Or:

```
A[B!=1] <- NA
rasterToPoints(A)[, 3]
```

etc...

Now why does this: `A[B[B == 1]]` not work? Unpack it:

```
B[B == 1]
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The cell values of `B` where `B==1` are, of course, `1`. `A[B[B == 1]]` thus becomes `A[c(1,1,1,..)]`, and returns the value of the first cell many times.

`A[B]` is equivalent to `A[B!=0]` as `B` is considered a logical statement in this case, and `0 == FALSE` and all other values are `TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

this should work for the 1 values:

```
A[B == 1]
```

as well as this, for the 0 values

```
A[B == 0]
```